# Problems with per-user subdomain sessions & Google OAuth2

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We're developing an application that hosts each user account under their own subdomain. Separate users may access their application through a domain such as usera.myapp.com and userb.myapp.com.

To enhance security between application accounts, the session cookies are scoped to the subdomain of the account (ex. usera.myapp.com instead of .myapp.com). This seems to pose a problem with Google's OAuth2 implementation. Since Google OAuth will only allow you redirect back to the set redirect_uri in their settings, we cannot redirect the user back to their custom subdomain after authorizing our app. We're forced to redirect them back a single generic subdomain such as oauth.myapp.com.

Once they're redirected, we no longer have access to the session (sessions are scoped to a different subdomain now). Since we no longer have access to the session, we cannot check the CSRF token we set to the "state" parameter when requesting the OAuth token. Most other implementations of OAuth2 will allow us to redirect back to a wildcard subdomain, so this isn't an issue.

Now we are left with 2 possible solutions to fix this issue...

1. Skip checking the CSRF token in the "state" parameter, which opens us up to clikjacking attacks. Or...
2. Open up our session cookies to use the entire domain, instead of scoping them to the the account subdomain. This opens it's own can of worms and security issues, but it is something that we can deal with.

Option #2 seems like the lesser of the two evils, but I'd like some input before we proceed with doing that.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, might it be possible to construct the state value by hashing up a bunch of pieces of state so you don't have to retrieve the desired value from a cookie?  E.g. hash up the subdomain, the time of day, and some internal system state from your app.  Then you can recompute the value you expect when they show up at oauth.myapp.com, no need to fetch it from the session.  Should be effective against clickjacking I’d think.